# left join on non primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I do a left join on tables A and B which have a common column but not the Primary Key of A or B.

The common column might have one or more records in both tables. I want to display all rows from Table A and pull additional data from B for those records from A. Is this possible?

Table A

```
Column1
1123
1123
1123
2234
2234
3344
```

Table B

```
Column1
1123
2234
2234
2234
2234
```

Desired Output

```
A.Column1 B.Column1
1123       1123
1123       1123
1123       1123
2234       2234
2234       2234
3344       NULL
```

Comment: yes, left join should work. select * from A left join B on A.col = B.col

Comment: @Rajesh left join on A on B with non primary key outputs more records than records in Table A. Am I using the wrong join?

Comment: do you want to pick only one value from B? can you give sample data and expected result to try out

Comment: Yes, Table B will only have one record for the many records in Table A. For e.g. Table A might have 1, 2, 3 or more records for ID1122 where as Table B will have only 1 record of ID1122

Comment: i have added a answer for this, check if it works, then you can accept.

Answer (score 1):

As per the latest comment and desired result, this query should work.
Need to get distinct values from TableB as there exists duplicate values.

```
SELECT A.COLUMN1 , B.Column1
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN1 FROM TableB ) B
on A.Column1 = B.Column1
```

Comment: I made an update to sample data in TableB. There could be more number of records in TableB for a record in TableA too

Comment: after running the query you gave it returns more records than records in TableA

Comment: Not sure why I am seeing more records... could you suggest anything I can look into? I checked TableA for nulls and non numeric values and I also added another Where clause to rid the non numeric... still the same result

Comment: @user793468, you should see all records from A and not more, u can create sql fiddle with all columns data, so it would be easy to debug

Answer (score 0):

You aren't required to have the primary key column in a `JOIN` (though, it usually is faster because of indexes). Just use your common field as the join criteria:

```
SELECT a.field, b.field2
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
  ON b.common = a.common
WHERE a.id = ???
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's anything special about the scenario you described.  Am I missing something?

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEA TA
LEFT JOIN TABLEB TB ON TA.COMMONFIELD = TB.COMMONFIELD
```

Comment: left join on A on B with non primary key outputs more records than records in Table A. Am I using the wrong join?

Comment: No, if there are X matches on the join criteria in table B for a particular record in table A, you will get X copies of the table A row joined with each matching row in table B.  If X = 0 you will just get the table A record with NULL for the table B fields - that is a property of the OUTER join.  If you use an INNER join, you would get zero rows in that scenario.

Comment: Not sure why I got downvoted...voter care to explain?

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from A
left outer join B on A.a = B.b
```